# App crushes on bad request and network error using fetch in react-native

Tags: react-native, fetch

My react native app crashes in .apk when fetch returns a bad request or network error
Below is the fetch function:

````
    try {
      const reponse = await fetch(
        'http://example.com',
        {
          method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body
        },
      );
      if (reponse.ok) {
        const data = await reponse.json();
        console.warn('Success response', data);
        return navigation.navigate('different', {
          token: data.token,
          memberNo: data.user.memberno,
        });
      } else {
        setStatus('Incorrect Details entered');
        // console.warn('Failed response', reponse);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setStatus('Network request failed connect to the internet');
      // console.error('CATCH Error', error);
    }
  }```
````

Comment: What did you try to solve the crash ? Have look at the documentation and do some research about bad request and the `fetch` function ?

Answer (score 0):

First check you API response may be its return something null or undefined and you used that in your screen.
e.g when we use flatlist and pass undefined and null then the apk crash so focus on your data format

Comment: Thank you.the fetch function wasn't the issue since i was using the UseEffect hook wrongly